# Is LCD digitizer different on iPad 2 for different languages?

Tags: hardware, ipad, repair

I have an iPad 2 from Japan as like to have ability to input Japanese characters. When recently trying to replace the screen and Wi-Fi antennae I managed to damage the LCD.

Before I go out and buy a replacement digitizer can anyone confirm whether these are all the same i.e is a digitizer for a US model iPad going to be different to one for a Japan model?

Answer (score 1):

No, all digitisers for a certain model of iPad are the same regardless of where the iPad was purchased. Input of Japanese characters is a software feature independent of the location where the digitiser was purchased.